# I want to select some random numbers but their addition should always be even in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

```
import random


for i in range(100):
    a = random.randint(1, 20)
    b = random.randint(1, 20)
    c = random.randint(1, 20)
    if ((a + b + c) % 2) == 0:
        print(str(a) + "," + str(b) + "," + str(c))
```

I tried this but I am not getting the desired output. I want it in a way that three random numbers are chosen between 1 and 20 such that their sum is always even. Here the programme prints only the outputs that are even it does not select the numbers in such a way.
Hope you help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

How about checking if the sum first two (a, b) is even or odd, and then accordingly set c?

```py
import random


for i in range(100):
    a = random.randint(1, 20)
    b = random.randint(1, 20)
    if (a + b) % 2 == 0:
      c = random.randint(1, 10) * 2
    else:
      c = random.randint(1, 10) * 2 - 1
    if ((a + b + c) % 2) == 0:
        print(str(a) + "," + str(b) + "," + str(c))
```

Comment: I think this code will never print the cases where `c`  is `19`. Also, the `if` condition checking (before printing) seems to be redundant.

Comment: About the if, you are right, but I keep it to show that this is working, and c can be 19, I just tested it (changed the if to `if c==19` and it printed 3 outputs).

Comment: Did you get `c` as `19` and at the **_same time_** the sum of `a`, `b`, and `c` added up to even total?

Comment: Yep, (BTW: the sum was always even)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
import random
from itertools import product

# Prepare a list of triplets that add up to an even number
even_triplets = [x for x in product(range(1,21), range(1,21),range(1,21))
                 if (sum(x)%2)==0]

# Now select 100 of those triplets randomly, allowing
# duplicates (allowing same triplet to appear multiple times)

result = random.choices(even_triplets, k=100)
# If you don't want repetitions, un-comment below line instead of above:
# result = random.sample(even_triplets, 100)

# Print the first and last of the selected 100 triplets, just to verify
print(result[0])
print(result[-1])
```

**Note:**
The way the question is phrased currently is a **self-contradiction**: it says that `a`, `b`, and `c` are to be selected **randomly**, and it also says that they should **add up to an even number**. If the selection of `a`, `b`, and `c` is truly random, then it cannot be subject to the additional constraint of adding up to an even number.

Comment: note that random doesn't imply uniformly distributed.  the way it's described, the marginal distribution of each random variable is indeed uniform, it's just that there's a constraint on the joint distribution excluding certain combinations.  to demonstrate that the marginals are uniform you can run, e.g., `collections.Counter([x[0] for x in even_triplets])` and see that every value appears the same number of times

Comment: @SamMason - Did you mean to type `for x in result` rather than `for x in even_triplets` ?

Comment: nope.  I meant the marginal of the whole distribution not any particular sample

Answer (score 0):

for completeness, a less efficient way of generating samples with this distribution would be to use [rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling).  this works by rejecting values that aren't wanted, in this case where the sum isn't even

```py
from random import randint

def fn():
  while True:
    x = tuple(randint(1, 20) for _ in range(3))
    if sum(x) & 1 == 0:
      return x
```

which can be used as:

```py
for i in range(100):
    a, b, c = fn()
    print(f'{a}, {b}, {c}')
```

rejection sampling can be wasteful, but on average we'd only expect to reject one sample for every one we accept so it's not too bad here